# Yum list security updates; understanding the output

Tags: yum

```
$ yum check-update --security
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/2016.03                                                                                                    | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/2016.03                                                                                                 | 2.3 kB     00:00     
No packages needed for security; 1 packages available
```

What this output means?

- What are loaded plugins?
- Are the two packages listed, security updates, or not?
- What does the last line mean?

Comment: That's not a constructive comment. I am asking a question.

Comment: Also if you are able to find an exact answer to this question in the documentation, please feel free to list it here :) But MikeA actually provided a helpful answer. Thanks for the trolling.

Comment: Thanks for ignoring advice on how to ask good questions such as http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before. U&L SE is full of questions that could have been avoided if their authors had carefully perused the docs and/or relevant resources in the first place.

Comment: This question is not answered in the documents. I already checked. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yum has various plugins for different things.  Check yum documentation or manpages to see what yours are for.
- Those are not packages, those are the yum repositories you have configured.
- There are no available security updates, but there is one non-security update available.